# How do I redo this code so I am only calling for one function?

Tags: python

The following code does what I want in the first function but in the second function if he makes an error it starts by reasking the first function while I only want it to ask the temperature again. Please keep in mind I am beginner and if you have a solution with global thats fine but please also show me a fix by calling the calling of a function with a variable

```
def number():
    num = int(input('Choose a number'))
    if num<0 or number>100:
        print ('Error number must be greater then 0 and less then 100')
        number()
    return num
def number_2()
    num = number()
    num2 = int(input('What is your temperature?'))
    if num<0 or number>120:
        print ('Error number must be greater then 0 and less then 120')
        number_2()
    if num>num2:
        print('You are good to go!')
```

Comment: Is the `number>120` supposed to be `num>120` or did I not see something?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry about that. I didn't copy and paste it I rewrote it in a hurry

Comment: line 6: `s/number()/num = number()/

Answer (score 0):

You reference 'number' several times, and it is not initialized, so I am not certain what you mean. However, this is a working script to achieve the separation of asking for num and num2.

```
def number():
    num = int(input('Choose a number'))
    if num<0 or num>100:
        print ('Error number must be greater then 0 and less then 100')
        number()
    return num
def number_2(num):
    num2 = int(input('What is your temperature?'))
    if num2<0 or num2>120:
        print ('Error number must be greater then 0 and less then 120')
        number_2(num)
    if num>num2:
        print('You are good to go!')
def run():
    num = number()
    num2 = number_2(num)
run()
```